# Adding APIT to NS2.35 Ubuntu 16.04 and I can't find the apit_packet.h file

Tags: ns2

After I edited the cmu-trace.cc file in ns2.35 to add APIT, many errors were created. Some of them are as follows.

I tried the solution provided by [Adding APIT in NS2.35 Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620205/adding-apit-in-ns2-35-ubuntu-16-04), but I can't find the apit_packet.h file.

Help me please. Thank you in advance.

```
trace/cmu-trace.cc: In member function ‘void CMUTrace::format_apit(Packet*, int)’:
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1077:45: error: ‘HDR_APIT’ was not declared in this scope
             struct hdr_apit *wd = HDR_APIT(p);
                                             ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1078:60: error: ‘HDR_APIT_BEACON’ was not declared in this scope
             struct hdr_apit_beacon *bcn = HDR_APIT_BEACON(p);
                                                            ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1079:57: error: ‘HDR_APIT_RSSI’ was not declared in this scope
             struct hdr_apit_rssi *rssi = HDR_APIT_RSSI(p);
                                                         ^
...
```

Comment: Source code, apit2d.zip → `{apit.cc, apit.h, apit_packet.h}` https://sourceforge.net/projects/posalgorithms/files/?source=directory ... **But**: These "Positioning Algorithms" ... are all **buggy / incomplete / unfinished** development projects → https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ns-users/fOy3XcBxtrU ... Search | apit | : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ns-users/apit%7Csort:date ... (and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ns-users/imapit%7Csort:date )

Comment: Dear Mr. Knud Larsen, I am very sorry.
My real error message is this:trace/cmu-trace.cc: In member function ‘void CMUTrace::format_mpolsr(Packet*, int)’:
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1175:46: error: ‘HDR_MPOLSR_PKT’ was not declared in this scope
  struct hdr_mpolsr_pkt* ph = HDR_MPOLSR_PKT(p);
                                              ^
trace/cmu-trace.cc:1180:5: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct CMUTrace::format_mpolsr(Packet*, int)::hdr_mpolsr_pkt’
   ph->pkt_src(),
     ^...................I look forward to your answer again.

Comment: Please follow all links in my first comment. All possible answers are at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-users ... and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47620205/adding-apit-in-ns2-35-ubuntu-16-04 ... Note : I never got any of the Positioning Algorithms to work !

Comment: »» HDR_MPOLSR_PKT was not declared «« :  There is no OLSR or MPOLSR in APIT or ns2. Are you trying to mix added protocols ? Not a good idea. You can have as many ns-allinone-2.xx as you want, installed at the same time https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FCjn-9fkR7tKeqClUpHsleaEdnoKRZzq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers to my questions, I am trying the solution you provided.